# What is the correct hierarchical schema.org markup for a category page of articles?

Tags: schema.org

I am working on a section of a website that is a combination of 'how-to' articles and 'faq' articles. When excerpted groups of those articles are displayed in a list by category I am not sure what schema to use for the container and the individual articles. Blog and BlogPosting is for blogs and this is not a blog. The articles are not dated or in chronological order. So I am thinking each one is either 'CreativeWork' or 'Article'. But I am not sure what the container's schema should be when they are displayed in excerpted groups or categories.

Edit: 
Just to clarify. 
Here's a simple version of my markup:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype=" ??????? ">
    <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"></article>
    <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"></article>
    <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"></article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't get too hung up on lists they are not as important [to the machine] as you think.

Try identifying the categories as well as you can.  Not having a view into your world, I'll pick a couple of random categories "World War II" & "Europe".  Create a page for each (quite possibly these could be your current list pages) and add the Schema.org specific to the category term itself.

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": ["Place","DefinedTerm"],
    "@id": "http://example.com/concepts/europe",
    "name": "Europe",
    "sameAs": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q46",
    ....

{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type":"DefinedTerm",
    "@id": "http://example.com/concepts/wwii",
    "name": "World War II",
    "sameAs": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q362",
    ....
```

Then for your articles use the `"about"` property to reference them to the categories:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type":"Article",
    "@id": "http://example.com/articles/A123",
    "name": "World War II in Europe",
    "about": ["http://example.com/concepts/wwii",
              "http://example.com/concepts/europe"],
    .....
```

That in theory is all you need to do for the crawler, which should have crawled all your pages, to understand you articles and what they are about.
If you want to be a  bit more explicit, on the category pages you could add in the reverse relationships using the `subjectOf` property:

```
    "subjectOf": ["http://example.com/articles/A123",
              "http://example.com/articles/A033"],
```

Lists of things are of more use to humans, whereas in the machines (eg. The Knowledge Graph) they can work it out from the relationship information you provide.